# Changing the size of a UITableViewCell based on the size of a subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I scale `UITableViewCell`s based on the amount of content in them? In my cells I use three labels which represent a forum. The labels are named "alias", "date", and "comments". The third label, comments, can be any number of rows. Therefore, I need my cells to become dynamically size, depending on the amount of text in the "comments" label. Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)pTextField
{
[self setLoadingState:YES];
[pTextField resignFirstResponder];

NSUserDefaults *userStorage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *alias = [self urlEncode:[userStorage objectForKey:@"alias"]];
NSString *email = [self urlEncode:[userStorage objectForKey:@"email"]];
NSString *who = [self getUniqueDeviceId];
NSString *comment = [self urlEncode:[pTextField text]];

comment = [comment stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
who = [who stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if([self isBlank:comment])
{
    [self setLoadingState:NO];
    pTextField.text = @"";
    return NO;
}
if([self isBlank:alias])
{
    [self showMessagePopup:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageMustChooseAlias", nil)];
    return NO;
}

[self.forumThreadDataProvider startSendPost:self.taskId : self.forumThreadId : alias : who : email : comment];

pTextField.text = @"";

return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ForumthreadCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Feedback *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *aliasLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *commentLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

[aliasLabel setText:item.alias];
[commentLabel setText:item.comment];
[dateLabel setText:[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(double)item.time]]];

commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[commentLabel sizeToFit];

return cell;
}
```

Ive tryed already myself with the following code-example but it failed big-TIME:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell) {        
UILabel *commentLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
return commentLabel.frame.size.height;
}  
else
return 30;
}
```

Comment: Try using the numberOfLines property. Or use core graphics helper methods to find the size that the text occupies for certain font size and use it to dynamically populate your content's size.

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial for [how to set dynamically set cell height](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/),

Basically you need to use methods like this to calculate the height of Laebl,

```
- (CGFloat)RAD_textHeightForSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size {
    //Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of the label
    CGFloat maxWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 50;
    CGFloat maxHeight = 9999;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth,maxHeight);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [self sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:size] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

    return expectedLabelSize.height;
}
```

Then you need to implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {  
    NSString *label = [self.aNote length] == 0 ? kDefaultNoteLabel : self.aNote;
    CGFloat height = [label RAD_textHeightForSystemFontOfSize:kTextViewFontSize] + 20.0;
    return height;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to use this example on my code, I wanna see how you would do it since I don't get it to work.. The label that I need to know the height of is commentLabel.....